# Change JENKINS_HOME on Red Hat Linux?

Tags: jenkins, redhat

I used this procedure to install Jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+RedHat+distributions

After it was up and running I discovered the /var/lib/jenkins partition on my server is very small.  I want to move it, but I do not want to change the user that it runs under.  I am new to Linux and I'm stumped.  How do I move it for example to my Home/Public folder?  The "Jenkins" user doesn't seem to have a Home folder.  Its running as a daemon on startup, so I have no idea where to configure those settings.
Can I create a Home folder for the Jenkins user? How?

I read this article:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins

but do not understand HOW to "set the new Jenkins home".  I have used the export command, and restarted the service, but the old path still shows up in the Manage Jenkins screens.

I've read the 2-3 similar questions on stackoverflow also, but there's always a big missing piece for me.  Where to find that file where I change the path permanently?

Comment: Would reinstalling it be easier?  How would I set the default location before running the yum command?

Comment: I have completely uninstalled Jenkins and am going to start over using another method.  I cannot figure out how to pre-configure the yum version to install to another location.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, for followers, it's OK to leave the jenkins' user home dir as /var/lib/jenkins [if you have enough space there], and just treat it as if it were a normal user home dir.

Answer (score 41):

Here's an easy way to solve your problem. First, move the Jenkins directory from `/var/lib/jenkins` to `/home/jenkins`. Then create a symlink at `/var/lib/jenkins` pointing to `/home/jenkins`. And of course, stop the Jenkins service before doing that.

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo mv /var/lib/jenkins /home
sudo ln -s /home/jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this will solve my problem if I can get IT to create /home/jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins works locally on the server, but I cannot access it from another computer via port 8080 anymore.  It worked before I moved everything.  HELP!

Comment: Are you sure it is not because of a firewall? I think it is enabled by default in RedHat. To verify try shutting it down with `sudo service iptables stop`

Comment: Positive its not the firewall.  Our IT dept couldn't figure out how to get it accessable from another computer.  :(  So I uninstalled it.  I am trying the other methods in Paul Becotte's link now.  VERY frustrating for a Linux n00b!

Comment: Very strange, I just don't see how this change can make it unaccessible from another computer. I've tried it myself and it worked for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me

Comment: You can also change `JENKINS_HOME` here: `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

Comment: If anyone impatiently stops their move command before completing (like me), you can continue the move process using `sudo rsync --remove-source-files -a /var/lib/jenkins/ /home/jenkins/`.

Comment: Does the mv command work across different partitions? Some older versions don't. So just use rsync from the outset. 'rsync -avzhP --remove-source-files /var/lib/jenkins /home/jenkins'.

Comment: I was using the htmlpublisher-plugin and after updating the Jenkins directory, it is still referring to the old one and publishing the .html report there instead of the new updated `/home/jenkins`, does anyone have an idea how to get this fixed?

Answer (score 16):

I managed to change the home location for Jenkins by modifying content of /etc/sysconfig/jenkins file as follows:

```
JENKINS_HOME="/home/jenkins"
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the config file is in `/etc/default/jenkins` on my Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, I reread your question a little bit more closely, lets see if we can figure this out.  I am going to list some info that you may or may not know.

1. The jenkins installation and jenkins home are not the same thing.  One is where the war file and other parts that jenkins needs to run live.  jenkins_home is where your data is stored.  By default, jenkins_home lives in ~/.jenkins.  When you start jenkins, it looks for an environment variable to tell it where to find those files.
2. Jenkins runs as a seperate user, which, by default, is jenkins.  This way it doesn't get in the way of you.  The jenkins user will not have access to YOUR home directory, so that would be a poor solution.  Ideally, it would have its own home directory, /home/jenkins.  Your home directory could then be /home/jenkins/.jenkins.  You say that folder doesn't exist- if you don't have access to it to create it yourself, that is perfectly fine, you can specify ANY folder.  However, the jenkins user must have ownership of that folder to read and write to it.
3. It looks like Jenkins on redhat will be running with tomcat by default.  The documentation for how to set environment variables for tomcat is https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat
4. This all gets set up with a script.https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JenkinsLinuxStartupScript seems to be the one that is used for this purpose.  Even if you don't know anything about shell scripting, this isn't too hard... lines with a # are comments.  The first line

   JENKINS_USER=jenkins

sets the name of the user account jenkins will be using.  Look down a littlle further, and you'll see the line

```
export JENKINS_BASEDIR=/home/jenkins

export CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_BASEDIR/jenkins-home -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

This lets you set a directory to where jenkins should live, and then sets the jenkins_home directory to that /jenkins-home.

For your application, you may want to do something like this

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkinsmount/home -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

That would then store all of your build data (which is the part that grows!) at /var/jenkinsmount/home ... while leaving the rest of your files in their current location.

I haven't used it on redhat, but hopefully I explained enough for you to actually understand what is going on so that you can get it going!

Other INFO:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Unix+daemon

Comment: Thanks for the link, that was some great info!  David's solution above worked for me.

Comment: Paul, can you give me an example of how to use daemonize?  I finally got it installed, but have no idea how to apply it to Jenkins. The jenkins.war file is in home/jenkins folder.  I'm stuck at that point.  Is it a problem if that folder can't be unmounted while daemon is running? http://linux.die.net/man/1/daemonize

Answer (score 7):

I have faced the same issue and question. 
Connecting some dots I could fix my Jenkins after I moved Jenkins to a new location due to the same issue -space in disk under /var/lib/jenkins.

Here is the procedures that I had to follow to get it working taking in consideration that I am pointing Jenkins to a non-default port. (I have applied this process into 2 servers)

First, move the Jenkins directory from /var/lib/jenkins to /opt/jenkins

```
sudo service jenkins stop
sudo mv /var/lib/jenkins /opt/
```

Now you can change your workspace and build directory to any other location on your machine.
Jenkins provides 3 predefined variables that can be used to specify the new location:

JENKINS_HOME — Jenkins home directory

ITEM_ROOTDIR — Root directory of a job for which the workspace is allocated

ITEM_FULLNAME — ‘/’-separated job name, like “foo/bar”

```
sudo su jenkins (access as Jenkins user)
JENKINS_HOME=/opt/jenkins
ITEM_ROOTDIR=/opt/jenkins
ITEM_FULLNAME=/opt/jenkins
exit (exit Jenkins user)
```

Now, edit the jenkins config

```
/opt/jenkins$ sudo nano /etc/default/jenkins
```

Modify the following line

```
#jenkins home location
#JENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/$NAME (here is the default)
JENKINS_HOME=/opt/jenkins (that is our new location)
```

change the home directory of a user

```
sudo usermod -d /opt/jenkins/ jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Would you know if it will keep this amended location on an upgrade?  Or are additional steps needed on every upgrade to keep this location?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is having issues with space and you have to relocate your jenkins, just wanted to reiterate that::

1. `sudo service jenkins stop`
2. `sudo mv /var/lib/jenkins /home`
3. `sudo ln -s /home/jenkins /var/lib/jenkins`
4. `sudo service jenkins start`

works great, so thanks to the person who posted that answer a few years ago!

Answer (score 1):

Richard Chen's location is where I found the jenkins file on my CentOS 6.6 system.

1. sudo service jenkins stop
2. mv /var/lib/jenkins /home/mylocation/
3. (made sure the new location had correct ownership and group-- Jenkins)
4. modified the content of the file /etc/sysconfig/jenkins as follows:

   JENKINS_HOME="/home/mylocation"
5. sudo service jenkins start

Answer (score 1):

If all these don't work, then the only solution that works is to edit the following file

```
/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service
```

then need to execute reloading of configs by running

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

after this restarting the service would reflect the change.

Answer (score 0):

Some commands work for me as below:

Step 1: Stop jenkin service and moving folder

```
systemctl stop jenkins
mv /var/lib/jenkins /whatever/folder
sudo chown jenkins -R /whatever/folder
```

Step 2: Modify jenkins home location in /etc/default/jenkins

```
JENKINS_HOME=/whatever/folder/$NAME
```

Step 3: Restart jenkins service

```
systemctl start jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

**[A]** Find your current jenkins home folder, if you are not aware where it is ? 
Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Check label 'Home directory' 
**[B]** To move current Jenkins home folder to a new directory. Follow below steps :-

1. Stop Jenkins service - by killing the process
2. Follow one of below approach to set new home folder for JENKINS.

   ```
   a) By default Jenkins home directory is set to ~/.jenkins
   b) "JENKINS_HOME" environment variable setup in operating system.
   c) "JENKINS_HOME" entry in JNDI environment.
   d) "JENKINS_HOME" system property to the servlet container.
           Tomcat context descriptor of the servlet, you can set below field in apache-tomcat-8.5.28/conf/context.xml :
           <Context ...>
             <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" value="/path/to/jenkins_home/" type="java.lang.String"/>
           </Context>

   e)  If jenkins.war file is deployed in a tomcat server , then even appending below content in bin/catalina.sh will setup JENKINS_HOME.
               CATALINA_OPTS="-DJENKINS_HOME=/path_to/jenkins_home/"
   ```
3. Manually copy Jenkins home folder content from old to new home
   folder. (use cp command) . Instead of moving, copy step is advised to keep one backup. Later you can delete old workspace.
4. Now start Jenkins, then It will pick the new home directory
   from the path mentioned in JENKINS_HOME variable.

   *Note: - Just by setting above variable "JENKINS_HOME" to a different path will not copy
   the files from current Jenkins home path to new one automatically. This copy step - you have to do it yourself, Manually.*