# "Unable to create home directory" error when changing JENKINS_HOME

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Jenkins was running all fine on a RedHat Linux machine (a clean EC2 machine on AWS), until I decided to change the `JENKINS_HOME`. I simply moved the Jenkins directory from `/var/lib/jenkins` to `/home/ec2-user/jenkins` and then created a symlink. (I followed the first answer to this question: [Change JENKINS_HOME on Red Hat Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839538/change-jenkins-home-on-red-hat-linux)).

However when I restart Jenkins I get the error:

> Unable to create the home directory ‘/var/lib/jenkins’. This is most
>   likely a permission problem. To change the home directory, use
>   JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set the JENKINS_HOME system
>   property.

I tried changing `JENKINS_HOME` in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`, setting it to the new folder (which I suppose defeats the point of a symlink?) and I still get the same error

> Unable to create the home directory ‘/home/ec2-user/jenkins’.

It is for backup purposes, so that I have all Jenkins data in a mounted external data storage (AWS Elastic File System).

Comment: You should answer your own question; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer Do not edit the answer into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. This error was persisting because the /jenkins/ folder needs to be accessible to user 'jenkins' to run processes, but it couldn't access this folder because it is belongs to the particular logged in user. I changed the mounting to /var/ where jenkins can access as global process, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, so sharing my solution here:
The user **jenkins** does not have access to the folder home/ec2-user/jenkins. You can modify the access rights of the folder home/ec2-user/home by changing or adding the user **jenkins** to owner

```
sudo chown jenkins /home/ec2-user/jenkins
sudo chmod u+w /home/ec2-user/jenkins
```

To verify the new ownership, you can do:

```
ls -ld /home/ec2-user/jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty obvious: "**This is most likely a permission problem.**"

I assume `/home/jenkins` does not exists, and the user `jenkins` does not have write permissions in `/home`. If you moved the Jenkins home, then you probably did it as root and just forgot to update owner permissions.

You would need to create the home, something like this:

```
sudo service jenkins stop
# make the changes in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
sudo mkdir --parents /home/jenkins  # or mv, in your case
sudo chown --recursive jenkins /home/jenkins
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: I moved the whole jenkins directory to /home/jenkins so it does exist. Nevertheless I've followed these commands word for word and it hasn't resolved the problem (same error message as before).

Comment: @ru111 If you moved the Jenkins home, I am guessing you did it as root (or some other user). I updated my answer: You would need to pass recursive to the `chown` command.

Comment: Thanks however the error is still there. I am thinking it may have something to do with permissions on the AWS elastic file system...

Comment: @ru111 This is obviously a problem inside the machine. Once the machine is up and running, AWS filesystem is no longer involved ... for the most part. But I have no other alternative to offer. Sorry.